# How to stop slideshow from changing size of body?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a website with a slideshow on the first page and when I open it on a pc it works as it should but when I open it on mobile the slideshow causes the size of the body to change. This is the code I have. I've already tried quite a few things but so far nothing has really worked.

```js
let slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

setInterval(showSlides, 11900)

function showSlides() {
  let i;
  let sfeerbeelden = document.getElementsByClassName("sfeerbeeld");
  for (i = 0; i < sfeerbeelden.length; i++) {
    sfeerbeeld = sfeerbeelden[i];
    sfeerbeeld.style.display = "none";
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > sfeerbeelden.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  sfeerbeeld = sfeerbeelden[slideIndex - 1];
  sfeerbeeld.style.animation = "fadeIn 5s";
  sfeerbeeld.style.display = "inherit";
  setTimeout(() => {
    sfeerbeeld.style.animation = "fadeOut 5s"
  }, 7000);
}
```

```css
body {
  background-image: url("Banner.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.sfeerbeeldencontainer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 70vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.sfeerbeelden {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  width: auto;
}

.sfeerbeeld {
  display: none;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.sfeerbeeld_img {
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="index">
  <div class="sfeerbeeldencontainer">
    <div class="sfeerbeelden">
      <div class="sfeerbeeld">
        <img src="Sfeerbeeld_1.jpg" class="sfeerbeeld_img">
      </div>
      <div class="sfeerbeeld">
        <img src="Sfeerbeeld_2.jpg" class="sfeerbeeld_img">
      </div>
      <div class="sfeerbeeld">
        <img src="sfeerbeeld_3.jpg" class="sfeerbeeld_img">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please include publicly accessible images - now we cannot run the snippet.

Comment: Are you saying that the width of the slideshow is too big on mobile devices?

Comment: @MHinfo The size of the slideshow itself is ok I but somehow because of the slideshow the whole body changes which also effects the elements other elements.

Comment: I have copied your code on CodePen (and adding online images), and according to what I see, the width of the images is too big on mobile devices. What you have to do is to put a relative unit (like `vw`) on your images, eventually with a `max-width`, or the relative unit in a `media query`

Comment: @MHinfo I set a max-width to my images and that solved the problem, thx